# Scala; recursively walk all directories in parent Hadoop directory

Tags: scala, hadoop, recursion

I have been trying to create a recursive function to walk all directories in a parent path of Hadoop. I have the following function below but the output is a bunch of nested arrays of objects so not exactly what I am looking for but it does walk the Hadoop path. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. My goal is to have the return type be an Array[Path].

> Get the bottom level partition paths of a giving parent directory example: parent `/hadoop/parent/path` with partitions `month`, `day` so in this case we would expect an array with 365 paths.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileStatus, FileSystem, Path}
val parentPath = "/hadoop/parent/path"
val hdfsPath: Path = new Path(parentPath)

def recursiveWalk(hdfsPath: Path): Array[Object] = {
    val fs: FileSystem = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(spark.sessionState.newHadoopConf())
    val fileIterable = fs.listStatus(hdfsPath)
    val res = for (f <- fileIterable) yield {
        if (f.isDirectory) {
            recursiveWalk(f.getPath).distinct
        }
        else {
            hdfsPath
        }
    }
    res.distinct
}
```

Comment: Given a parent directory, Spark already reads all files and folders within

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a recursive function that generates an array (for loop) of either:

- the output of the function if the item is a directory, which is an array of objects.
- a `Path` if it is a simple file.

This explains the fact that you obtain nested arrays (array of arrays).

You can use `flatMap` to avoid that issue. It transforms (or "flattens") a list of list of objects to a list of objects. Also, to obtain the type you expect, you need to have matching types between your stopping condition and your recursion (`Array` of `Path`). So you need to wrap `hdfsPath` inside an array.

Here is how to quickly fix your problem based on what I just wrote:

```scala
def recursiveWalk(hdfsPath: Path): Array[Path] = {
    val fs: FileSystem = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(spark.sessionState.newHadoopConf())
    val fileIterable = fs.listStatus(hdfsPath)
    val res = fileIterable.flatMap(f => {
        if (f.isDirectory) {
            recursiveWalk(f.getPath).distinct
        }
        else {
            Array(hdfsPath)
        }
    })
    res.distinct
}
```

The code above fixes the problem but to avoid having to use distinct, you can put the condition on the input file instead of its subfolders like below. You can also define the file system once and for all outside of the function.

```scala
val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem(conf)

def recursiveWalk(path : Path): Array[Path] = {
    if(hdfs.isDirectory(path))
        hdfs.listStatus(path).map(_.getPath).flatMap(rec _) :+ path
    else Array()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:

```
def recursiveWalk(hdfsPath: Path): Array[Path] = {
    val fs: FileSystem = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(spark.sessionState.newHadoopConf())
    if (fs.isDirectory(hdfsPath)) {
      fs.listStatus(hdfsPath).flatMap(innerPath => recursiveWalk(innerPath.getPath))
    } else Array.empty[Path]
  }
```

or if you need files in dirs also use:

```
def getDirsWithFiles(hdfsPath: Path): Array[Path] = {
    val fs: FileSystem = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(spark.sessionState.newHadoopConf())
    if (fs.isDirectory(hdfsPath)) {
      fs.listStatus(hdfsPath).flatMap(innerPath => getDirsWithFiles(innerPath.getPath))
    } else Array(hdfsPath)
  }
```